# MediaSize does not work for Selenium Chrome driver Print to PDF

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I shall expect this to print in A2 paper size. But the output remains legal. I tried other paper sizes to no avail.

Python, Selenium, and Chrome are of latest builds.

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = 'file:///C:/Users/XYZ/Downloads/page_1.html'

# Set app state
app_state = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True,
    "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
    "isLandscapeEnabled": False,
    "version": 2,
    "mediaSize": {"height_microns": 594000, "width_microns": 420000}
}
profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState':json.dumps(app_state)}

#STart
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile) 
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) 

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
driver.quit()
```

An alternate version with `"mediaSize": {"height_microns": 594000, "width_microns": 420000, "custom_display_name": "A2"}` does not work either.

Comment: @KJ Mediasize is a dict. See [this link](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blame/main/chrome/browser/resources/print_preview/data/model.ts).

Comment: @KJ I did it by adding the style tag; so, thanks. The mediasize variant in your last comment was already tried out by me to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pagesize parameter like this

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = 'file:///C:/Users/XYZ/Downloads/page_1.html'

# Set app state
app_state = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True,
    "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
    "isLandscapeEnabled": False,
    "version": 2,
    "pageSize": "A2"  # Set the pageSize directly
}
profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(app_state)}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile) 
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) 
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
driver.quit()
```